# Binary counter: base 10 adjustment

Tags: binary

In a microcontroller (MSP430F5659) the RTCB timer provides clock-based interrupts at register-controlled intervals.  These may be 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024 (and higher) interrupts per second.  The same timer also provides a 1-second interrupt which is handy for evaluating the problem below.

Using one of the clock-based interrupts I'd like to update a variable called milliseconds.  For reasons of efficiency and precision, I'm using the 1024 times per second interrupt.

Each interrupt represents 0.9765625 milliseconds. I don't want to store milliseconds as a float value, but rather as an integer.

I suppose incrementing a floating point variable by 0.9756525 and then rounding would do the trick, but I'd rather not add floating point processing overhead.

Therefore I need a mathematical function that will set my millisecond counter appropriately so it stays within +-1 ms.  So, each time the interrupt fires, a decision is made whether or not the millisecond counter should be incremented (or wait until the next interrupt).

Comment: Can't you just store number of interrupts (integer) and calculate time from it only when it is needed later (simple division)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your master counter count *interrupts* rather than milliseconds. Then whenever someone needs a millisecond count, convert your interrupt count to milliseconds on the fly:
$$ \mathit{millis} = \frac{1000}{1024}\mathit{intrs} = \mathit{intrs} - \frac{3\cdot \mathit{intrs}}{2^7} $$
where the division is just a bit shift.

Comment: That's the ticket!  Another day, another "why didn't I think of that?!" moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a second counter running and avoid incrementing the millisecond counter at 22, 65 and 107. At 128 this second counter should be reset to zero.